# How to know the factory/default router SSID broadcast name after possible name change?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

my router's SSID name is Thomson123456 and I changed it to Deydap.
My question is, is there any way someone to find the default router name, especially the six characters after Thomson/Speedtouch and so on ?

Thank you

Comment: ssid broadcast name?

Comment: @Logman Yes, i edited my title

Comment: Why are you after this information?  Even if you don't broadcast your SSID your access point CAN still be found.  What is the signifcance of the 6 digits after the name.

Answer (score 2):

A passerby could find out the make and model of the router by looking at its MAC address (which is available before trying to connect) - if the last 6 digits of the SSID are truly random (and not based on the MAC address or otherwise guessable) then they wouldn't be able to 'find' it as such.

The interesting question is why do you care? If you've changed the name of the router and have a suitably unique and secure WPA key, then whether or not someone can find the routers original SSID is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: Do you know any software that will allow me to see the default ssid  ?

Comment: The only way to find out the default SSID is to perform a factory reset on the router. And you may find that it randomly generates the numeric part when you do this (so 2 resets give you different SSIDs) - so there may not actually be a single 'default' value as such.

Comment: No its not ok ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that using the factory reset on the router itself may reset this. It all depends on whether the default is part of the routers software though some algorithm, or if it is something set by your ISP prior to shipping the router to you.